# How to get the value of my button in JSP and show it on the tomcat log and eclipse consol

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

what im trying to do is get a message when the user click the button a message appear on the console and on the tomcat logs

```
        <input type="button" value="Buscar" id="btnBuscar" name="btnBuscar" onclick="setTimeout(gotoPage(1),3000)" style="width: 100px"><br>
        <%
        System.out.println("page should refresh itself in 3 seconds" );
        %>
```

Comment: You do realize that the button is on the client, in the Web Browser, and Tomcat is on the server, right? Nothing will happen on the server unless you *communicate* with it, e.g. using Ajax. Or are you asking us to teach you Ajax?

Comment: the thing is i dont have access to the server side so to find out whether they applying the changes i want a message display on the tomcat logs which is the only way i can see if the fix work or no and this project im working on doesnt use ajax just classic old jsp and java code.

Comment: You don't have access to the server side, but want tomcat logs, *which are on the server*, to write something?!?!? How did you envision changing the server code to write something if you don't have access to the server code?

Comment: i can view the tomcat logs with notepadd++ using NppFTP

Comment: In what way is that relevant to changing the server code to write to the log?

Comment: Is this perhaps an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), and what you really need is the Web Browser console, so your client-side web browser javascript code can write log messages there that you can see, and that this doesn't have anything to do with the server?

Comment: i have the code in a local environment which allow me to modify than send the modification via email as for the server  i can view the tomcat logs with notepadd++ using NppFTP working for a big company and already develop code from 10 years ago a real hassle...

Comment: And that would work too ill see into it.

Answer (score 0):

The button will generate a JavaScript event. You must make that event to send a request to the server, and get the server processed by a Servlet or JSP.

This may help you:

[Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

[How to call servlet when button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505347/how-to-call-servlet-when-button-click)